# Powershell activate Windows 10 WMIMethodException

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to activate Windows 10 with PowerShell.

I got the following script:

```
$computerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$key = "[Windows 10 product key is in here]"
$activationService = Get-WmiObject -Query "select * from SoftwareLicensingService" -ComputerName $computerName
$activationService.InstallProductKey($key)
$activationService.RefreshLicenseStatus()
```

But I keep getting the following exception:

```
Exception calling "InstallProductKey" : ""
At F:test.ps1:4:1
+ $activationService.InstallProductKey($key)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WMIMethodException
```

I just can't seem to get this right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is correct! 
I used the following to activate my notebook

```
$computer = gc env:computername
$key = "XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX"
$service = get-wmiObject -query "select * from SoftwareLicensingService" -computername $computer
$service.InstallProductKey($key)
$service.RefreshLicenseStatus()
```

Answer (score 0):

Launch `cmd` as Administrator and run:

```
slmgr.vbs /ipk xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx
```